# SQL Server 2012: Is There a Way to Select Columns Dynamically WITHOUT sp_executesql?

Tags: sql-server

I'm pretty sure the answer is going to be 'No', but just wanted to double check.  I have a website that allows users to select which columns they want to see on reports.  These columns are stored in a sql table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[colNames]
(
    [colID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [colName] [varchar](100) NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_colNames] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([colID] ASC)
                    WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
                          IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
                          ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 80) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

INSERT INTO [dbo].[colNames]
Select 'schoolNo'
UNION
Select 'locationName'
UNION 
Select 'locationAlias'
UNION
Select 'schoolLevel'
UNION
Select 'schoolArea'
Union
Select 'stateClassification'
```

The users select the fields via dropdown box, and the IDs are returned to a SQL Server stored procedure as a string parameter, so if they chose locationAlias, schoolArea, and stateClassification, the string would look like this: '2,4,5'

The table to query against:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[location]
(
    [schoolID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [schoolNo] [varchar](7) NULL,
    [locationName] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [locationAlias] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [schoolLevel] [varchar](5) NULL,
    [schoolLevelAbbrev] [varchar](5) NULL,
    [schoolLevelDescription] [varchar](25) NULL,
    [schoolArea] [varchar](25) NULL,
    [stateClassification] [varchar](10) NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_location] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([schoolID] ASC)
                    WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
                          IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
                          ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

Insert Into location 
Select '001','Doss High','Doss','03','H','High','2','A1'
Union
Select '002','Stuart Middle','Stuart','02','M','Middle','3','A1'
Union
Select '003','Trunnel Elementary','Trunnel','01','E','Elementary','5','A1'
```

So the dynamic query would look like:

```
Select  locationAlias, schoolArea, stateClassification
From    location
```

This is a very simplified version of the queries I have to build, most of them are long and complex. I know how to build out a dynamic query by creating a variable and writing the query into the variable and calling sp_executeSQL, but they are a pain to modify and debug. I was hoping that by SQL Server 2012, there would be an easier way to build queries with dynamic columns, that maybe I'm not aware of? Any suggestions?

Comment: You are right, the answer is **`NO`**. Sorry

Comment: Actually yes, just write the column names in the SELECT clause. That's available since the 1970s. That won't help you if you write complex queries though, that try to do more than they should. I suspect you don't understand that a SQL statement **is** your source code. Changing it results in different programs, ie execution plans. The column names and tables are *not* parameters, they are the fundamental building blocks. That's why no SQL dialect allows you to just pass a list of column names.

Comment: *Why* do you think you need variable column names passed outside the query? If you want to use different columns from the client's side, just specify the columns you want. You can automate this with an ORM and/or LINQ.

Comment: Finally, reporting tools always provided column selection without loading entire rows into memory. They never required a dynamic list of columns, the created the `SELECT` clause themselves. They also allow users to specify different columns *per report*, not just per user

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos `write the column names in the SELECT clause` isnt that dynamic sql?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza no, it's just plain-old SQL as it was available since the 1970s. `sp_executesql` is used to execute strings and pass parameters. No-one said the string has to be generated using T-SQL or that there is *any* advantage in doing so

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos So you are saying this need dynamic sql, but the sql string can be calculated someone else? Im confused because looks like you want move the logic to the application instead of keeping it on the db like the OP have it now.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza reporting tools *are* applications.

Comment: Thanks for the quick feedback, you bring up good points. I was hoping to filter on the server side so that a smaller stream of data would be passed back to the client.  I'm trying to stay away from third party software and have developed a website that uses html5/bootstrap/jquery. As I mentioned this was an example, my site is highly customizable and allows each user to save literally everything (schools selected, columns selected, etc.) for every different report independent of each other. All of their options are saved in the database.

Answer (score 1):

There are ways to do what you want but it will get way more complex than just writing out the dynamic sql.

I have found a free tool on the internet that works pretty well. [Static SQL Converter](http://sql-tuning.com/convert-static-sql-to-dynamic-sql/)

This will give you a good skeleton to work off of. You will have to take away a few extra single quotes and pipes '||' other than that is works pretty well.

Another way that I found that helps is running a

```
PRINT @SQL
```

then you can see the exact SQL you are running and you can mess with the quotes until you et it right without having to guess at it.